# Error: plug-in not found: RefasterRuleCompiler

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, errorprone

I am trying to create **.refaster** rules using [Google Error Prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone) library for my project.

My project is using **Maven** & **JDK 17** and has the following **pom.xml**:

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_refaster</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xplugin:RefasterRuleCompiler --out ${project.basedir}/../emptystring.refaster</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                            <version>2.23.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I'm executing the command `mvn clean install`, the following error is thrown:

```
Compilation failure
plug-in not found: RefasterRuleCompiler
```

Also, I have added the following configuration in the **.mvn/jvm.config** to run with JDK 17 like indicated in the official documentation:

```
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED
```

**Note:** I started a project with **Error Prone Core** before also and I have succeeded to run with JDK 17 but when I try to run the project with **Error Prone Refaster**, it's failing.

Also, I set the `JAVA_HOME` to **JDK 17** and tried running the project from the terminal, the error still persisted.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try cleaning your local Maven repository by deleting the contents of the .m2 directory (usually located in your home directory). Then, run mvn clean install again to redownload all dependencies.

Comment: @AnkurSaxena 
I tried now, but the result was the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Please read the docs properly.

I followed the **Official Docs from Google Error Prone** [here](https://errorprone.info/docs/installation).

Couple of things need to be fixed.

- Firstly, you will need to add `error_prone_refaster` dependency in your `annotationProcessorPaths` to make the plugin work.

This will fix the error: **Error: plug-in not found: RefasterRuleCompiler**.

**Note:** This was not mentioned in the docs. I had to do hit and trial method to get to the solution.

Otherwise, you will face `Error: plug-in not found: RefasterRuleCompiler` if you don't add `error_prone_refaster` dependency to the `annotationProcessorPaths`:

```
➜  maven-error-prone-test git:(master) ✗ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< org.example:maven-error-prone-test >-----------------
[INFO] Building maven-error-prone-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: plug-in not found: RefasterRuleCompiler
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.526 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-26T20:45:15+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project maven-error-prone-test: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: plug-in not found: RefasterRuleCompiler
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

So, it's mandatory to add it.

- In the **RefasterRuleCompiler** plugin, you will need to pass the **Refaster Rule/Template** class. For example: If you have created a template class called
  **StringIsEmpty.java**, then you have to pass it to **RefasterRuleCompiler** plugin to generate the necessary **.refaster** file for you.

I saw that you missed to do it. So, fix this please.

**Example on how I did:**

```
<arg>-Xplugin:RefasterRuleCompiler --out ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/refaster_files/emptystring.refaster ${project.basedir}/src/main/org/example/StringIsEmpty.java</arg>
```

---

**Scratch Project for demonstration:**

**Project Structure (Before running `mvn clean install`):**

[image]

**StringIsEmpty.java (example code taken from Google Error Prone):**

```
package org.example;

import com.google.errorprone.refaster.annotation.AfterTemplate;
import com.google.errorprone.refaster.annotation.AlsoNegation;
import com.google.errorprone.refaster.annotation.BeforeTemplate;

public class StringIsEmpty {
    @BeforeTemplate
    boolean equalsEmptyString(String string) {
        return string.equals("");
    }

    @BeforeTemplate
    boolean lengthEquals0(String string) {
        return string.length() == 0;
    }

    @AfterTemplate
    @AlsoNegation
    boolean optimizedMethod(String string) {
        return string.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Working **pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-error-prone-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <error-prone.version>2.23.0</error-prone.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
            <version>${error-prone.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_refaster -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_refaster</artifactId>
            <version>${error-prone.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xplugin:RefasterRuleCompiler --out ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/refaster_files/emptystring.refaster ${project.basedir}/src/main/org/example/StringIsEmpty.java</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_refaster</artifactId>
                            <version>${error-prone.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                            <version>${error-prone.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**`mvn clean install` success logs:**

```
➜  maven-error-prone-test git:(master) ✗ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< org.example:maven-error-prone-test >-----------------
[INFO] Building maven-error-prone-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/target/maven-error-prone-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ maven-error-prone-test ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/target/maven-error-prone-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/example/maven-error-prone-test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-error-prone-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/anish/maven-error-prone-test/pom.xml to /Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/example/maven-error-prone-test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-error-prone-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.502 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-26T20:39:21+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Project Structure (after running `mvn clean install`):**

[image]

As you can see the **.refaster** file was generated :)